# Nested child dom-repeat not updating if parent dom-repeat data is updated

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymerfire

I have the following nested dom-repeat:

```
<firebase-query
  id="query"
  path="[[path]]"
  data="{{parentItems}}"
  app-name="myApp">
</firebase-query>

<template is="dom-repeat"
            items="{{parentItems}}"
            as="parentItem">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{_toArray(parentItem)}}">
      <div>{{item.details}} </div>          
    </template>
 </template>
```

When items are added/removed from `parentItems`, the nested child dom-repeat template is not re-rendering i.e. _toArray() is not called. Is this behaviour expected? How do I ensure that when `parentItems` changes, the nested template will also be updated? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the details of how you add something in the parentItems property, but i assume you do something like this

```
this.parentItems.push(something)
```

Polymer won't see the array change in that case, try to use the polymer push instead,

```
this.push('parentItems', something)
```

It will push it in the array, and notify polymer binding to update the view.

Comment: Thanks for responding. i'm using firebase-query to update parentItems. I've updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: Ok, normally firebase-query is doing the right calls for the polymer databinding, so it must be something else. I can't test with firebase for now, but I'll try it later.

Comment: Right, I think this is what is happening. parentItems is an array of objects. I had expected that when the object mutates, it'll trigger the nested dom-repeat. In this case, what should I do to ensure that the nested dom-repeat is triggered when the object in the array changes?

Comment: It can be a tricky one, the first thing I'd try would be to add an observe="object object.prop" attribute to my dom-repeat and watch the path of the values that can change. If this don't work, I think I'll need more code too help :)

Comment: Thanks. Yeah its tricky cause the keys are random firebase unique ids... :(